# iPhone: How to run a Beta build, in addition to the App Store build?

Tags: iphone

I have an app on the Store for which we’re readying an update.

The other members of our team have the App Store version already loaded up (~purchased) on their respective iPhones -- and those contain **User Data** which each member needs to be able to **keep**.

In the meantime, we need to test out a Beta version of the *next* version of the app.

Presumably, we’d need to have the two versions (ad hoc, and app store) co-existing on each device, at least until everyone’s signed off on the beta and it’s uploaded to the store (at which point, they'd delete the beta version).

[Once it’s on the Store, of course, they can each update their main (i.e., Release) version of the app via the usual App Store 'update' mechanism.  In that case, all their user data is still retained intact.]

So assuming that’s the proper workflow ...

How do I issue a Beta to the team, and have it not replace/overwrite the existing App Store version?

I’ve tried customizing parameters in the beta’s “[appname]-Info.plist”, but haven’t found a setting yet that allows the two versions (beta and release) to co-exist on the same device.

Any ideas?  And is this is the proper approach to them being able to keep their data?

(And last, how might I do it with & without a script?  I assume there's just one parameter that'd need to be changed.)

I hope this all makes sense -- thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Unfortunately, you do not tell us which parameters in the Info.plist you have tried to modify. It is my understanding that the bundle identifier is the one Apple uses to uniquely identify an app. Did you try changing it?

Comment: Thank you, Ole.  Please see comment below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you want to have two versions of the same application on one device?  I don't think there's a way to get this effect -- updating an application, which keys on unique CFBundleIdentifier, replaces old version bundle but not data.

For the effect you want, you must have two distinct applications.  They need different CFBundleIdentifiers, so they won't overwrite each other.  They then cannot share data, so you'll have to arrange for export/import involving an off-device shared space.

If you don't want this hassle, issue the team extra devices and test on those.  The team's primary devices remain on the AppStore version.  You must still export/import to bring content from the test devices to the primary devices.  Any paid content each has on the App Store version should be available for their beta, though, as usual for app upgrades and one-owner multiple-devices scenarios.

Comment: Thank you, Ole & Joseph, for the feedback.  I believe I tried the Executable file name, and the Bundle name, but not the Bundle Identifier.  Will check it out.  (For what it’s worth, I just ran into a different issue that precludes testing this for the next few days; but I’ll report back.)  Also for what it’s worth, they don’t need to share data between the two versions of the app -- just not lose their existing data in the main (i.e., Release) version.  [And there isn’t any data kept in the cloud in this case, just local data in the App Store version kept on a single device.]

Comment: [As I say, I'm having a separate, unrelated issue which precludes testing on my device for the moment.]  But I did just test this solution using the Simulator, and it appears to work.  For what it’s worth, what appears to make an application “distinct” from another does appear to be that Bundle Identifier.  (In fact, in this case, these are essentially two versions of the *same* app; but because the Bundle ID is different, the Springboard treats them as unique.  So in essence, you can load up an arbitrary number of 'instances' of an app, as needed, by varying the Bundle ID.) THANK YOU both!